# Como criar um certificado SSL local em Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl

Como posso criar um certificado SSL local em Windows?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode criar um certificado das seguintes formas:

### [PowerShell (Windows 10 e Server 2016)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps):

1. Abra o PowerShell;
2. Use o comando `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "endereço do seu site", "outro endereço do seu site" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"` para criar o seu certificado;

---

### [makecert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx):

1. Faça download do [`makecert`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279);
2. Após instalar, abra a linha de comandos;
3. Use o comando `makecert -r -pe -ss my -sr CurrentUser -n "CN=NomeDoSeuSite" -sv "NomeDaChavePrivadaDoSeuCertificado.pvk" NomeDaChavePublicaDoSeuCertificado.cer`

Explicação das opções:

```
-r // cria um certificado assinado por si
-pe // marca a chave privada como exportável
-ss my // Nome da *store* onde o certificado vai ser colocado
-sr CurrentUser // Localização da *store*
-n "CN=NomeDoSeuSite" // Nomes no certificado 
-sv "NomeDaChavePrivadaDoSeuCertificado.pvk"
```

(Mais exemplos [aqui](http://www.yangsoft.com/blog/?p=105)).

---

Comment: Só lembrando. Abrir o powerrshell como administrador para evitar erros